# How to output text in the R console without creating new lines?

Tags: r, newline, rstudio, output-formatting

I would like to output a progress indicator during my lengthy running algorithms. I can easily "bubble up" a progress value from within my algorithm (e.g. via invoking a provided function callback specifically for this purpose), but the difficulty is in the actual text output process. Every call to `print` creates a new line, and each prefixed with `[1]`.

**Is there a way to print at different moments in time, without introducing line breaks?**

To be concrete, I want to achieve an "animation" that would look like the following if observed at two different times.

```
0%...
```

...

```
0%...2%...4%...
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use `cat()` instead of `print()`:

```
cat("0%")
cat("..10%")
```

Outputs:

```
0%..10%
```

Answer (score 13):

Bah, Andrie beat me to it  by 28 seconds.

```
> for (i in 1:10) {
+ cat(paste("..", i, ".."))
+ }
.. 1 .... 2 .... 3 .... 4 .... 5 .... 6 .... 7 .... 8 .... 9 .... 10 ..
```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you can yse `plyr`

```
  l_ply(1:4,function(x) x+1,.progress= progress_text(char = '+'),.print=TRUE)
  |                                 |   0%[1] 2
  |++++++                           |  25%[1] 3
  |+++++++++++++++                  |  50%[1] 4
  |++++++++++++++++++++++           |  75%[1] 5
  |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ |  100%[1]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you really need a progress bar as such, use `txtProgressBar` for console output. Or `winProgressBar` under Windows for a windowed progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are looking for `\r` in the `cat` function like below:

```
for(i in 1:100) {
    cat('\r',
            i,
            '% |',
            rep('=', i / 4),
            ifelse(i == 100, '|\n',  '>'), sep = '')
    Sys.sleep(.1)
}
```